# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Runtime in Activity's inner class

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, aar

I have found a lot of similar questions, but no one helps me.

I have next problem. I have complete project for Android and I have to export it's functionality to `.aar` library. First of all I created new project and created new module where put my source project. At this step all things goes well and I get my `mylib.aar` file in `/build/outputs/aar/` folder. Then I created new project to test my `mylib.aar`, so I created `libs` folder under my `app` folder in Android Studio, and in `build.gradle` file of my test project I added these lines:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {dirs 'libs'}
}

dependencies {
    compile(name: 'mylib', ext: 'aar')
}
```

In manifest file I added declaration of MainActivity from library:

```
<activity android:name="com.testlib.mylib.MainActivity"
            android:label="MainActivity"/>
```

Android Studio found this file well and I even can watch source code through built-in decompiler. But when I try to start this activity from another activity that isn't placed in my lib I get this error:

```
3838-3838/com.testapp.testsdkapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testapp.testsdkapp, PID: 3838
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.testlib.mylib.MainActivity$RegisterInBackgroundTask
            at com.testlib.mylib.MainActivity.registerInBackground(MainActivity.java:1551)
            at com.testlib.mylib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:269)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

`RegisterInBackgroundTask` is inner `public AsyncTask` class declared in my MainActivity in the library. I tried to put `mylib.aar` in `aar` folder and declare in `build.gradle` in other way, but it didn't help me and I get similar error.

If this information is not enough, I'll add required parts of code etc. So please help me, if you know how to solve my problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

import mylib.aar as module in your project and inside dependencies add following line

```
  compile project(':mylib')
```

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.2 and I can't import .aar library as module.

Comment: that is possible i am using same

Comment: please describe more in details

Comment: right click on project select "Open module settings" then press + sign available in left top and complete wizard

Comment: thanks in advise, but this solution didn't help me and I get same error ;(

Comment: compile project(':mylib') added this

Comment: yes, I guess without this line it wouldn't see my classes in manifest file

Comment: then it is not import related issue check in the code

Comment: In the code I have simple AsyncTask and I don't know why it doesn't see this class, I've made it public just in case, but also didn't help

Comment: what exactly you are calling share that line

Comment: new RegisterInBackgroundTask().execute(null, null, null);

Comment: yes, this is the line from MainActivity in library that crashes the app, in test project I'm just starting this activity and AsyncTask is automaticaly starts in onCreate().